# How do I open an existing query in SQL Server 2012 Management Studio?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2012

I'm a beginner and in class we're learning how to make tables, insert records, make foreign keys all through query.

I've made a 3 tables through query but now I have to edit a previous table through it's own query but I closed it already. How do I open it again so I can add something to the table? All I see is the "New Query" button.

The tables are all in one file, under one database.To be more specific, I want to open query window that shows up when you click "New Query" but I want to see the codes I wrote to make the table because I need to edit something there.

Comment: you can open through file>open>file(on top left hand corner) or `CTRL+O`

Comment: Try going through this tutorial or any youtube tutorial to make yourself familiar with editor :https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/menu-help/open-with-new-file

Comment: If you want to see the DDL that was used to create the table and the constraints you can script it out.  Right click on the table > Script table as > CREATE to > New Query window.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to re-open closed table script if it has not been saved in a .sql file. Check Kyle's comment above for single table. Re-generate the script.

For more than one table, right click on Database name, Select Tasks->Generate Scripts-->Click Next --> Select all tables you want. Save script on clipboard. Paste in New Query. Save that file as SQL.

You can use advanced options also to generate the same script.

Answer (score 0):

If you have saved your query earlier then open the folder which contains the sql code. Double click on that file, it will automatically open in SQL Server Management Studio.